# Bootstrap Switch, how to remove the border radius of the whole switcher

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-switch

I just used bootstrap-switch - v3.3.1, I don't need the border radius so I set `border-radius:0 !important;` to `.bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-focused` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/q2zEk/1/.

```
.bootstrap-switch.bootstrap-switch-focused {
    border-color: #cacaca;
    outline: none !important;;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

But we can see that there are a small radius border inside the switcher.

How can I change the entire switcher to square border, without affecting the global switchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by setting :

```
/**wrapper border*/
.bootstrap-switch
{
    border-radius: 0px;
}

/**on/off border**/
.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on , .bootstrap-switch-handle-off {
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q2zEk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you inspect the element in your jsFiddle, scroll down a bit & `.bootstrap-switch` has a border-radius of 4px.

Unchecking that gets rid of the radius on the blue switch.

So try this (you may need to use !important):

**CSS**

```
.bootstrap-switch {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

@Jaskey is also on the right track.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2zEk/2/)

Comment: No help, would you please give me a jsfiddle link?